# Django API attribute not found

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, scikit-learn, pickle

I am building an API using django and the django rest framework that uses models from tensorflow and scikit-learn. I have ran into an error where my CountVectorizer that I fitted and used in another python script and used pickle to export and import into my django project, raises an attribute error when I try to make a call to the API View. This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dude/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/chatbot/views.py", line 36, in chatbotRequestHandler
    chatbotObj = ChatBot()
  File "/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/chatbot/functions.py", line 100, in __init__
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'custom_preprocessor' on <module '__main__' from '/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/manage.py'>
[25/Nov/2023 00:23:44] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 96891
```

This is my api view:

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
    data = request.data
    chatbotPrompt = StockGrab(str(data['Chatbot_Input']), None, None)
    chatbotObj = ChatBot()
    chatbotResponse = chatbotObj.chatbotResponse(chatbotPrompt)

    return JsonResponse(data={
        "Chatbot_Output":chatbotResponse
    })
```

This is the part in my functions.py where I load the models and import the StockGrab and ChatBot objects from:

```
class ChatBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.model = load_model('/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/chatbot/chatbotModels/chatbot_model.keras')
        with open('/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/chatbot/chatbotModels/vectorizer.pkl', 'rb') as file:
            self.vectorizer = load(file)

        with open('/home/dude/Desktop/Projects/Finance Webapp/Financial_Chatbot_API/chatbot/chatbotModels/label_encoder.pkl', 'rb') as file:
            self.encoder = load(file)
```

I have tried different methods of importing the objects.

```
from .functions import StockGrab, ChatBot
from .functions import StockGrab, ChatBot, custom_preprocessor
from . import functions
```

I have tried using joblib instead of pickle but get the same error.

I have tried re doing my training and make new files for the models.

I am out of ideas for debugging and could use some help.

Comment: `custion_preprocessor`? Consider editing your code in the question under *”I have tried different methods of importing the objects.”*